# Angular Displaying Multiple Buttons for a List

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a list of cells. And I am trying to display its Location Reference for another screen. The way I want to display that property is in the shape of buttons. I want to have 1 button per cell and on the button, I want to write the Location Reference of the cell. Right now, the cells are too much, so I don't want to add them one by one. I tried to use `ng-repeat` but I couldn't make it work and it gave many errors. What should I do to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="LocationReference in cell">
      <td>
        <button>{{ cell.LocationReference }}</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
cell: ICell;
```

Cell Interface:

```
export interface ICell {
  CellId?: number;
  CellName?: string;
  LocationReference?: string;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Angular` or `AngularJS`? `ng-repeat ` is used in `AngularJS` and you tagged your question as `angular`.

Comment: I'm using `Angular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat is for angularJS, in the tags you say you are using angular. Angular is different from angularJS, in [angular you can use ngfor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

If you have a list of cells, you need to loop through your cells, and not over the property of one cell. Also it totally doesn't make sense to put your button in a single cell, so I removed the table construct. Use a table only if you are displaying tabular data.

If you are displaying tabular data, add the table structure back, but now you should see how this is supposed to work: cells is the array for all your cells, should be of type ICell[]

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
  <button *ngFor=let cell of cells>{{cell.LocationReference}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I don't have any errors, but I can't see the buttons on the screen what could be wrong?
`<mat-tab *ngIf="warehouse?.WarehouseType?.Id !=5">
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <mat-icon class="mr-8">format_list_numbered</mat-icon>
                        Görünüm
                    </ng-template>
                    <div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
                        <button *ngFor="let cell of cells">{{cell.LocationReference}}</button>
                      </div>
</mat-tab> `

Comment: Is the HTML getting rendered but you don't see them? Then it's most probably some CSS issue. If the HTML is not getting rendered make sure you have the correct information in your `cells` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `*ngFor` and not `ng-repeat`. `ng-repeat` is used in `AngularJS`, and `*ngFor` is used in Angular. If you will loop through an array you can do it like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
  <div *ngFor="let item of cell">
    <button>{{ item.LocationReference }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you will loop through a dictionary you can do it like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
  <div *ngFor="let key of cell | keyvalue">
    <button>{{ item.value}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```